# How do I restore my contacts list to the left side of my Gmail?

Tags: gmail, google-contacts

I want to restore my contacts in the left side of my emails and not separate on the right corner.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid that can't be done with the 2018 Gmail redesign. Contacts is now really a standalone app.